# window.performance.getEntriesByType unit test with jasmine

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, window, navigation-timing-api

I have a function in my Angular service that does a "this.window.performance.getEntriesByType('navigation')".

But I can't mock it.

Here is my service.spec.ts :

```
    const mockWindowService = jasmine.createSpyObj('WINDOW_TOKEN', ['performance']);
    Object.defineProperty(mockWindowService, 'performance', {
        value: {
            getEntriesByType: { windowPerformanceFixture },
        },
    });

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
        providers: [
            { provide: WINDOW_TOKEN, useValue: mockWindowService },
        ],
    });
```

// My windowPerformanceFixture object is in an external file

here is the error I receive :

```
TypeError: performance.getEntriesByType is not a function
```

Do you know how to mock this ?

Comment: Why would you want to mock a built-in method?

Comment: My function calls "this.window.performance.getEntriesByType('navigation')" so I have to mock it otherwise I get an error "performance.getEntriesByType is not a function"